# Inserting a .tex image into my LaTeX document

Tags: graphics, axodraw4j

I'm using a program that exports images in a `.tex` format and I was wondering if anyone know how I should include this in my main TeX file?

```
\fcolorbox{white}{white}{%
\begin{picture}(162,306)(271,-175) 
\SetWidth{1.0} 
\SetColor{Black}
\Line[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=5,arrowwidth=2,arrowinset=0.2](272,-174)(35‌2,-94)
\Line[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=5,arrowwidth=2,arrowinset=0.2](352,-94)(432,-174) 
\Photon(352,-94)(352,50){7.5}{7} \Line[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=5,arrowwidth=2,arrowinset=0.2](352,50)(432,‌130)
\Line[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=5,arrowwidth=2,arrowinset=0.2](272,130)(352‌,50) 
\Text(368,-14)[lb]{\Large{\Black{$\gamma$}}} 
\end{picture}}
```

Comment: `\input{yourimagefile.tex}` instead of `\includegraphics[...]{...}`. If you want resizing, use `\resizebox` from graphicx` package.

Comment: tex isn't really an image format? is this just a tex wrapper that includes an image (as in fig or gnuplot's combined tex/iimage exports?) in any case if it is TeX `\input{...}` should work.

Comment: There must be a duplicate some where here. Couldn't find it right now.

Comment: Almost certainly Harish but I couldnt either so thought I'd ask.  Yes it probably is David it looks like this in case your interested:

Comment: \begin{center}
\fcolorbox{white}{white}{
  \begin{picture}(162,306) (271,-175)
    \SetWidth{1.0}
    \SetColor{Black}
    \Line[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=5,arrowwidth=2,arrowinset=0.2](272,-174)(352,-94)
    \Line[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=5,arrowwidth=2,arrowinset=0.2](352,-94)(432,-174)
    \Photon(352,-94)(352,50){7.5}{7}
    \Line[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=5,arrowwidth=2,arrowinset=0.2](352,50)(432,130)
    \Line[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=5,arrowwidth=2,arrowinset=0.2](272,130)(352,50)
    \Text(368,-14)[lb]{\Large{\Black{$\gamma$}}}
  \end{picture}
}

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX.

Comment: Cheers Harish!!

Comment: @JackMedley You can [edit] the question if you want to provide additional information or code.

Comment: @JackMedley In my view, syntax spit out by "Using a program" looks wrong. see [picture environment examples](http://www.ursoswald.ch/LaTeXGraphics/picture/picture.html#SECTION00021000000000000000). Using graphics editor to spit out `.tex` looks great shortcut, but it's not foolproof and mislead you over time. Instead it's better to learn and get hands dirty to have _freedom_ by choosing one of [chronological list of graphics for Drawing with TeX](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=drawing). may be add a image/hand-drawn picture with your MWE code effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a complete example of your code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{axodraw4j}
\usepackage{color}
\setlength\unitlength{1pt}
\begin{document}

\framebox{\fcolorbox{white}{white}{%
\begin{picture}(162,306) (271,-175) 
\SetWidth{1.0} 
\SetColor{Black} 
\Line[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=5,arrowwidth=2,arrowinset=0.2](272,-174)(352,-94) 
\Line[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=5,arrowwidth=2,arrowinset=0.2](352,-94)(432,-174) 
\Photon(352,-94)(352,50){7.5}{7} 
\Line[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=5,arrowwidth=2,arrowinset=0.2](352,50)(432,130) 
\Line[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=5,arrowwidth=2,arrowinset=0.2](272,130)(352,50) 
\Text(368,-14)[lb]{\Large{\Black{$\gamma$}}} 
\end{picture}}}

%\input{<file>.tex}  % instead of the above code

\end{document}
```

[image]

If the package `axodraw4j` is not already on your system then you have to install it manually. It is not on CTAN!

Comment: Hi Herbert,
Thats exactly the diagram I need however when I compile (with: 'pdflatex Filename.tex') it only draws the little gamma without any of the lines? Are you compiling with a different command?
Cheers!
Jack

Comment: it needs the sequence `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`

Comment: I was compiling with pdflatex before which worked ok - apart from the images.  and it errors immediately when I try and run latex->...

Comment: Nevermind! I sorted it.  Cheers

Answer (score 2):

The code that you show in a comment looks on the surface like LaTeX syntax, but it is definitely not LaTeX out of the box, as commands like `\Line`, `\Photon`, `\Text`, etc. aren't defined by LaTeX. Thus as part of the program that you used to produce this code, there has to be some "package" (a file with the extension `.sty`, or perhaps `.dtx` if it isn't unpacked) that defines those commands.

Search for that file and then load it in the preamble of your document as

```
\usepackage{<name-of-package>}
```

and at the point you want your graphic appear

```
\input{<mygraphic>.tex}
```

Without a clue what the program is that you used, this is all guesswork of course.